# Alternative way to scrape from search engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For a work I am doing, I need to query Google (or a similar search engine) for around 40K times. I am only interested in the number of hits returned for a query. I wrote a script to do that, but I get stuck at around the 100th query, and I am getting 503 error. Obviously, there is a limit.

The question is, what are the alternative search engines and Python APIs that would let me query items limitlessly?

The following code is what I have tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from random import randint

def get_count(word1, word2):
    time.sleep(randint(5,15))   
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                     params={'q':'"'+word1+' '+word2+'"',
                             "tbs":"li:1"}
                    )
    while not r:
        print("****** wait ... "+str(r))    
        time.sleep(randint(10,100))
        r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                     params={'q':'"'+word1+' '+word2+'"',
                             "tbs":"li:1"}
                    )
    if r.ok:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        res = soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text
        if res:
            try:
                return int(res)
            except:
                print(res.split())
                if res.startswith('About'):
                    return int(res.split()[1].replace(',', ''))
                else:
                    return int(res.split()[0].replace(',', ''))

        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: This is pretty broad, it would help to post code, versions of python,. and associated libraries. In general I think 503 is probably you getting blocked so you could try using a "fake user agent" or you can slow down your scraping to seem more human or put less of a load on the server.

Comment: list of proxies + good proxies rotation + timeouts + list of google's datacenters IPs for requests will get you further, also slowing down your scraping.

Comment: You could use google's api, but it offers only 100 queries per day (for free). About the alternatives, try ask.com or searx.me.

Comment: The API is not a viable solution given the narrow purpose of only seeing the number of hits for a query as part of a class project. The other two websites seem to either be too limited in their scope of search or simply of poor quality. Seems I am outta luck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in R, but here is an Excel/VBA solution for you.

```
Sub Gethits()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set var1 = html.getelementbyid("resultStats")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Put your search terms in ColumnA, and run the script.

[image]

Comment: The question is in Python, not R or VBA

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid being blocked is to [rotate `user-agents`](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/) or by adding proxies to your request headers.

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want rather than making everything from scratch and maintain it over time or figuring out why your requests got blocked since it's already done for the end-user.

Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=fus%20ro%20dah) and the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/search-api) with all available parameters such as `async`, `pagination`, `localization`, `geo` support, and other advanced parameters.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

# random words
words = [
  "rigid",
  "terrific",
  "attraction",
  "yellow",
  "enlarge",
  "familiar",
  "green",
  "insert",
  "stop",
  "infuse",
  "pastoral",
  "female",
  "salve",
  "ceaseless",
  "fanatical",
  "record",
  "rhythm",
  "apathetic",
  "wise",
  "untidy",
  "thoughtless",
  "damp",
  "fancy",
  "fairies",
  "mistake",
  "key"
]

for word in words:
  params = {
      "engine": "google",
      "q": word,
      "hl": "en",
      "gl": "us",
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  }

  search = GoogleSearch(params)
  results = search.get_dict()
  
  try:
    results_count = results['search_information']['total_results']
  except: results_count = None
  print(results_count)  


------
'''
312000000
231000000
14410000000
8340000000
304000000
13280000000
20850000000
15300000000
3700000000
78600000
187000000
18570000000
155000000
18600000
3110000000
8610000000
15800000
12820000000
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.